# Blackberry- how to make ListField Headers above each row

Tags: java, blackberry, listfield

So i have a custom ListField class, and it looks pretty boring with no headers.  Does anyone know if there is a way to make headers above each cell?  I am used to iphone programming which made this very easy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There isn't a built-in feature, but you can just add a Field above it, or use yourScreen.setTitle()/setBanner() if you want it to remain on the screen regardless of scroll position.

Comment: so how do i add fields about each cell in the one ListField

Comment: Ah sorry, thought you were just referring to the entire list as a cell. The easiest way would just be to setRowHeight() to give yourself some more room, and then just paint the extra info/graphics/whatever int drawListRow(). Unfortunately you won't be able to have differing row heights, so keep that in mind when deploying.

Comment: Yeahhh that may make things difficult, I'll have to use something else besides a listField I'm thinking.  Thank's for your help!

Answer (score 0):

1. Replace the ListField with a VerticalFieldManager to contain your rows.
2. Move the draw code of your rows from the ListView to a custom Field class's paint method.  Or if it's a simple text row, use a LabelField.
3. Create another custom Field to contain your headers, or use another LabelField.
4. Add headers and rows to the VerticalFieldManager in the order you want them to appear.